# Processing windows messages, threading COM objects

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, wndproc

I have an application that captures Windows messages sent to the Form, and runs a method if an update is made to the system Clipboard:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:

            if (IsClipboardListenerOn)
                OnClipboardChanged();

            break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

In some instances I don't want my method, `OnClipboardChanged()`, to run. My solution was to set a static global variable `IsClipboardListenerOn` and toggle it as necessary. This didn't get the job done because the Windows message wasn't processed till *after* my function that did the toggling returned, so it was always true:

```
private void some_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm.IsClipboardListenerOn = false;

    // some code that makes the clipboard changed message fire

    MainForm.IsClipboardListenerOn = true;

   // when this returns the WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message gets caught
}
```

The next idea was to run the code that triggered a message event on a thread and wait for the thread to return to ensure it executed while the global flag was toggled off:

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => clipboard_stuff());
    thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    MainForm.IsClipboardListenerOn = false;

    thread1.Start();        

    thread1.Join();
    MainForm.IsClipboardListenerOn = true;
```

But this didn't work, either. In fact, sometimes it would execute my OnClipboardChanged() method twice. I know the system Clipboard requires Single Threaded Apartment; Is this part of my problem? Am I going about this wrong? Is there some other technique I can utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, that's not going to work.  Windows is waiting for you to start pumping messages again.  A workaround is to delay setting the flag back to true until all pending messages were dispatched.  That can be elegantly done by using the Control.BeginInvoke() method.  Like this:

```
private void some_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm.IsClipboardListenerOn = false;
    // some code that makes the clipboard changed message fire
    //...
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MainForm.IsClipboardListenerOn = true));
}
```

With the assumption that some_event() is a member of a form.  I'd guess that MainForm.BeginInvoke() would work as well.

Comment: Throwing a NullReferenceException. some_event is the delegate for a ToolStripMenuItem click event. My global flag is defined as: static public bool IsClipboardListenerOn = true;

Comment: I can't tell what your object references look like.  Pick something not null :)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just not familiar with your LINQ based code. There shouldn't be anything null there. Your calling a new Action object and instantiating it with an anonymous delegate? Do you mind spelling it out for a little more what your code is actually doing?

Comment: This is not Linq, just a lambda expression.  The exact same animal you used in your own code in the Thread constructor.  The code just passes a delegate object to the form's BeginInvoke() method.  Just like you passed one to the Thread constructor.

Comment: Yeah lambda, my mistake. I guess I just don't understand what could be null there. I'll try to further my understanding and continue to debug. I'll be back to update the questions status when I get it, thanks.

Comment: It turned out to be a class scoping issue... Curious it actually compiled and ran. Solution worked great.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there should be a cleaner solution than what I'm about to suggest, but you know what they say... if it's stupid and it works, it's not stupid.

If you're sure you're going to trigger a clipboard message that you'd like to ignore, set a flag and let the `WndProc` shut it off:

```
private void some_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm.SkipNextClipboardMessage = true;
    // some code that makes the clipboard changed message fire
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE: 
            if (SkipNextClipboardMessage)
                SkipNextClipboardMessage = false;
            else                    
                OnClipboardChanged();
            break;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Another terrible idea that's bound to get some stinkeyes from readers is to do as you did in your first version of the code, and add a call to `Application.DoEvents()` after inducing your clipboard changing method to force messages to be processed.

Yes, yes, it's evil and I'm going to hell, I know.